# Feature files require some loader file to run

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to run the Feature file using cucumber in Cypress 10.2.0.

It is throwing me an issue of "WebPack Compilation Error"

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/e2e/BankManagerLogin.feature 1:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `cypress.config` file needs adjusting to clear that error.

Try this, it's bolier-plate code from the badeball repository.

This assumes you have Typescript (let me know if you're only using Javascript).

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import * as webpack from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

async function setupNodeEvents(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              exclude: [/node_modules/],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "ts-loader",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              test: /\.feature$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
                  options: config,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue:  "type annotation can only be used in typescript files"
I guess this is the issue of not using .ts file. 
Can you give me an answer that would be applicable to both extensions? at sometime I use .ts and sometimes .js

Comment: Easiest to tell you the difference - in this code, `: Cypress.PluginEvents`, `: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions`, and `: Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions>`  are type annotations. Just delete them to get a non-typescript version.

Comment: I'm having syntax error now with the imports. 

C:\Cypress\Sample Project\cypress.config.js:1
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Yeah that's an annoying one, because it's a bit of a "fake" error. Trying to remember what causes it.

Comment: If you just have JS, you can try `const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");`  instead.

Comment: And the others would be `const webpack = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");` and `const { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");`

Comment: still getting error. 

Error: Cannot find module '@cypress/webpack-preprocessor'
Require stack:

Comment: Ok - anything you `import` or `require()` that's from a package, you have to add the package to the project. Are you using `npm` or `yarn`? Whatever you use, it's the same as the way you added `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Comment: Please tell me you have added `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`.

Comment: Do you mean npm install --save-dev @cypress/webpack-preprocessor ?

Comment: Indeed, that should do it.

Comment: So after everything you suggested, I did. 
But still, I'm getting the same issue which was mentioned in the start. 

"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"

Comment: What version of `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` (in package.json)?

Comment: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.3.0"

Comment: I just ran a non-typescript project to check out the steps. Simplest template would be [esbuild-cjs](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/examples/esbuild-cjs/cypress.config.js). There are two extra installs for this template - `@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor` and `esbuild`. The sample test [here](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#write-a-test) works with that setup. You may need some tweaking of your existing tests, but try that sample test to verify the setup is correct.

Comment: I have tried everything. 
my all isntallation is same but no clue.
how about we hop on some meeting and  you can see what's going on?
maybe there will be some small missing thing

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?